# How to recover accidentally deleted softlink folder(/bin, /lib,...) from ubuntu wsl2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

The real directory(/bin,/lib are deleted while the real direcotries:/usr/bin,/usr/lib still exist.) but I can't go into the system anymore.I try to run command like

`wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 ln -s /usr/bin /bin`

But it returns error "Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/E_UNEXPECTED". Is there any way to recreate the link direcotry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that:

```
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 -e /usr/bin/ln -s /usr/bin /bin
```

... will work.  Without the `-e`, it's still attempting to pass the command through to `/bin/bash` (which is the default shell for the root user) and failing. The `-e`/`--exec` tells WSL to *directly* run the `ln` command without invoking another shell.

You should also be able to launch into the shell with:

```
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 -e /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc
```

This would skip any potentially problematic startup files.

Comment: Thanks! It works.